# I need to add a print() method to the contact object, which will output the contact data to the console in the following format: name: number

Tags: javascript, node.js, methods

I am working on a Contact Manager app.I have created the contact object constructor, which has two arguments, name and number.I have a given code declares two objects and calls their print() methods.I need to complete the code by defining the print() method for the objects.

I tried:

```js
print=function(){

    console.log("name:"" number" )

}
```

But it brought an error

Comment: You have invalid syntax.

Comment: Yes syntax is wrong, It should be something like this: 

const print = function() {
    console.log({"name": "number"})
}

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong syntax, i think code below is better:

> print=function(){
> console.log(`{name}: ${number}`)
> }